# create index return "nothing happened"

Tags: neo4j

When I execute the query "CREATE INDEX ON :Label(propertie);", the index is not created.

I tried on neo4jshell and browser (v3.0.4).

On neo4jshell, it said :

```
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
<Nothing happened>31 ms
```

And the command "index --indexes" always returns :

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ index --indexes
Node indexes:

Relationship indexes:
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `index` command in the shell returns legacy indexes (see `help index`), not the schema indexes introduced with neo4j 2.

Try `schema` instead, this shows the new constraints/indexes.